# Exclusive solution sets?

Tags: prolog

Suppose we have:

```
g(0,0).
g(0,1).
h(1,2).

f(Z,X):- g(Z,X).
% Match h IFF g does not match
f(Z,X):- \+ g(Z,X), h(Z,X).
```

So we have a rule, f, that can decide to exclusively take solutions from g, or from h, both never from both:

```
f(A,B) is true IF: 
  g(A,B) is true, or
  h(A,B) is true and g(A,B) is false).
```

```
?- f(0, X).
X=0 ;    % solution from g
X=1 .    % solution from g
?- f(1, X).
X=2 .    % solution from h
```

Is there are better version of this that:

- doesn't require the negation operator, and
- when h is matched, doesn't require redundantly trying to disprove `g` a 
  second time, which may be expensive of have other unwanted side effects (such as IO).

---

OK... this is not quite XOR, which would be

```
f(A,B) is true IFF: 
  g(A,B) is true and h(A,B) is false, or
  h(A,B) is true and g(A,B) is false).
```

... but a similar issue applies: Can we avoid negation. Can we avoid redundant re-proving?

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
g(0,0).
g(0,1).
h(1,2).

f(Z,X):- g(Z,X).
f(Z,X):- \+ g(Z,X), h(Z,X).
```

If `Z` and `Y` are fresh in the last line, the query is " "Fail if there is any `g(_,_)`, otherwise `h(Z,X)`".

Observe:

```
?- f(0,1),f(0,0),f(1,2).   % f(1,2) is TRUE
true ;
false.

?- bagof([X,Y],f(X,Y),Bag).   % f(1,2) is NOT TRUE
Bag = [[0, 0], [0, 1]].
```

**The program is inconsistent.**

On the other hand:

```
g(0,0).
g(0,1).
h(1,2).

f(Z,X):- g(Z,X).
f(Z,X):- h(Z,X), \+ g(Z,X).
```

```
?- f(0,1),f(0,0),f(1,2).
true ;
false.

?- bagof([X,Y],f(X,Y),Bag).
Bag = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2]].
```

**The universe has been saved from total annihilation!**

That being said:

1. Negation-as-failure is not bad, in fact it is essential. Don't avoid it for no reason. It is also nonmonotonic, so what! We are not modeling in First-Order-Classical-Logic, we are just pretending to work in First-Order-Classical-Logic to get some programming done.
2. If you have "other unwanted side-effects" there is a design problem with the program. Does imperative code have "other unwanted side effects"? I hope not!
3. There is no "redundant matching". You would just be able to avoid "redundantly proving" `g(Z,X)` (or the negation) at that point if you *already knew* the truth value of `g(Z,X)` at that point of the clause, but you don't. People don't worry about "redundant comparison with the limit" in for loops either.
4. Is it "expensive"? Not more than a positive query.

Comment: Well, duplicate side effects. Any duplicate, redundant proof search. If we go enter the second f clause, we (the programmer) must know that g(Z,C) must be false, so why ask for it again? My interest in prolog is particularly for controlling search. It seems the program could be refactored to avoid reasking more questions about g when we decide to ask about h.

Comment: @user48956 I understand now. In that case: Use Enigmativity's idea. Or the "implication operator", `f(Z,X):- g(Z,X) -> true; h(Z,X).`.

Comment: This finds just `X=0` and misses `X=1`.

Comment: You can't have a statement, f(Z,X) that is true IFF g(Z,X) is true and h(Z,X) is false, OR  h(Z,X) is true and g(Z,X) is false), and find there are two solutions f(0,X)?

Comment: @user48956 Yes, you are right. You HAVE to "ask for it again". Doesn't look like there is a way around it.

Comment: Hmmm... Tabling is a solution. Seems like overkill though.

Comment: @user48956 Well, you can always store the g/2 found in a list or an AVL tree and look things up in there.

Comment: f(Z,X):- g(Z,X) -> true; h(Z,X). Does seem like the right answer. I don't get why it returns a single proof. There are two solutions.

Comment: `f(Z,X):- g(Z,X) *-> true ; h(Z,X).` Seems to get all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you happy using a cut?

```
g(0,0).
g(0,1).
h(1,2).

f(Z,X):- g(Z,X), !.
% Match h IFF g does not match
f(Z,X):- h(Z,X).
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is like giving a placebo to a patient to calm his nerves because negation is implemented with the cut...

Comment: Which is kind of why I asked if a cut was ok.

Comment: I'm OK with cuts, but f(0,X). finds a single result. It should find two.